# Proving that for each a, b in R, exists x in Q such that x is in (a, b)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove using the axiom of Archimedes that $\forall a, b \in \Bbb{R}, \; \exists x \in \Bbb{Q} : x \in (a, b)$

I did it in this way:

Since $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, I can write it as $\frac{l}{k}; \quad l, k \in \Bbb{Z}$

Since $\Bbb{R}$ is symmetric with respect to the origin, Is not restrictive to suppose $a, b \in \Bbb{R^+}$ and $l, k \in \Bbb{N}$.

$x \in (a, b) \implies a<x<b$

It's not difficult to prove with the axiom of Archimedes that $\exists \; x > a$
 (just think $x$ as $d*f; d\in \Bbb{Q}$ and $f \in \Bbb{N}$).

Now I have to prove that $\exists \; x<b$. As I said, I can write $x$ as $\frac{l}{k}$, with $l, k \in \Bbb{N}$

$\frac{l}{k}<b \implies l< b*k$.

Since $b$ is real and $l$ and $k$ natural, the axiom of Archimedes ensures that exists an appropriate $k$ for which the inequality is verified.

I think it's right, but I'm not sure. Can you please tell me what you think?

Thanks,

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've shown that, given $a,b>0$, the exists $q>a$ and $q'<b$, $q$ and $q'$ rationals.

Let $a,b$ be reals. By your arguments there exists $q$ rational such that $0<q< b-a$. By the archimedian property $nq> a$ for some natural $n$. Fix the smallest such $n$. You should be able to show that, if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $a<nq<b$.

If $a <0$ repeat the argument for $(\max\{-b,0\}, -a)$, and argue that this is enough.

Comment: Ok, so I've proved that exist two numbers q and q' that verify the equations respectively, but not that those numbers are equal, right? I don't know how to prove that for the same n and q, a<n*q and n*q<b

Comment: Exactly.  Try following the idea that I ve given.

Comment: The idea is that $q>0$ is small enough that this is going to happen for some $n$.